# How to parse the following string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
// Want as "1000002"
//------ 
Now:

1000002  <!DOCTYPE html>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head><title>  

</title></head> 

<body>     

<form method="post" action="./login.aspx?Username=adva%40gmail.com&amp;Password=2016%40dva&amp;ACCtype=2" id="form1"> 

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="XQ2BV7Dr7lA++91QctHt7heGp4A8FLFR2kRsS7h6jbkxUqmgw1T1NuQoCDfeWcipk/cOt6d/wTLMVkN0oIriBHcL06cfjFi7F78LLwZxhqo=" />  <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C2EE9ABB" />   
<div>
</div>     
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

// I want "1000002" in string

Comment: when and where you get this string

Comment: while requesting from service | http://mobilemcatch.mcommsg.com/login.aspx?Username=adva@gmail.com&Password=2016@dva&ACCtype=2

Comment: I want to parse and get the visible value as string. iOS app's login page

Comment: This has to be more complicated than you describe as the simple answer is take the first 7 characters (or first word). So what do you actually need and what have you tried to get it?

Comment: Now i'm printing this line::::: NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);::::: responce is :::

Comment: Response: 1000002

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./login.aspx?Username=adva%40gmail.com&amp;Password=2016%40dva&amp;ACCtype=2" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="AzhinaoWec/u1uf25GEnqxpRrzNUiXbZHcEQjL84vO0ZC5wDpAXu50+w9I2ti2WmomXDgP//g0OPHbXXxgpmU0i/2Vj87IGMuElei+m87uI=" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C2EE9ABB" />
    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I want only "1000002"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the actual cause of this problem is the .aspx page which you're calling to get this data.

[Your .aspx URL](http://mobilemcatch.mcommsg.com/login.aspx?Username=adva@gmail.com&Password=2016@dva&ACCtype=2)

This .aspx page appears to be pretending to be a webservice, posting your 1000002 value, but then letting ASP.Net *also* output its own (blank) HTML webpage afterwards.

You probably need your login.aspx page to contain something like this:

```
int yourLoginID = 1000002 ;        //  Or whatever..!

context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", yourLoginID));
context.Response.End();
```

This'll make sure the .aspx page only returns your number... nothing else.